# A man is in court because a company wants his prostheses back

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I forgot the title of the short story.

It is about a man who is in court because of his prostheses.

If I remember correctly he was a famous motorbiker.

A company wants all his prostheses back, because of financial stuff (don't remember exactly).

That includes half his brain, which makes loud noises.

The end of the story is:

> he gets to keep the prostheses.

I read this story in German in my philosophy class in 2008 or so (but it was definitely older). I don't remember which author it was or whether it was translated from another language.

I am not sure if it was in a book with other stories, because we just got a printout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "Do you exist, Mr. Jones?" (alternatively translated as "Are you there, Mr. Jones?") by [Stanisław Lem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem):

- The protagonist, Harry Jones, is an auto racer.
- During his career, he had suffered multiple injuries and had all of his organs, including his brain, replaced by luxury prostheses.
- His brain, manufactured under the brand name "Geniac", is a repurposed tabulator, which makes loud noises when Jones is thinking hard.
- The prostheses were financed and he had defaulted on the loan.
- The manufacturer or the prostheses, the company named "Cybernetics, Co.", is seeking to repossess the prostheses in the court of law.

> The court is unable to make a decision, because it is unclear whether Mr. Jones is a natural person (who cannot be repossessed) or property (that cannot be sued)

This story discusses the question of personal identity (similar to Theseus's Ship or Grandfather's Axe, but in humans).